# Python issue with threading.timer/for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, timer, enumerate

been going around in circles on this code for a while and could use a hand.
it's probably something small i missed somewhere.

i have a CSV file that im trying to pry some values out of, for our purposes it looks like this:

```
columns : A, B, C, D
row[0]: bad, x, y, s
row[1]: good1, x, y, z
row[2]: good2, x, y, z
```

Section of my Code looks like this:

```
def match_file():
    global name,
    aziVal1 = 'z'
    with open(path_address, 'rb') as userdataCSV:
        reader = csv.reader(userdataCSV)
        for row in reader:
            for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
                if aziVal1 in row:  
                    columns[i].append(v)
        name = columns[0]
        print name
    return
```

If i run this code one at a time from terminal , it works fine and gives an output of

```
['good1', 'good2']
```

but when i try to automate this with threading.Timer,

```
def altogether():
    threading.Timer(3.0, altogether).start()
    match_file()
    return
```

this becomes the output

```
['good1', 'good2']
['good1', 'good2', 'good1', 'good2']
['good1', 'good2', 'good1', 'good2', 'good1', 'good2']
['good1', 'good2', 'good1', 'good2', 'good1', 'good2', 'good1', 'good2']
```

I really don't know what's wrong with it.  I've tried deleting the global variables but i need that for another function, also tried shifting around the indentations to no avail.  Could really use a hand around here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset columns in the beginning of every loop.

```
def match_file():
    global name,
    aziVal1 = 'z'
    columns = []
    with open(path_address, 'rb') as userdataCSV:
        reader = csv.reader(userdataCSV)
        for row in reader:
            for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
                if aziVal1 in row:  
                    columns[i].append(v)
        name = columns[0]
        print name
    return
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! i finally figured it out i had declared columns as a global variable up top by mistake! that one line you added really pointed that out in the code. thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's beacause of this:

```
def altogether():
    threading.Timer(3.0, altogether).start() # You're passing this same methode into the timer.
    match_file()
    return
```

With toher words, when you call the methode altogether. You start a Timer, which also starts this method, which starts a new Timer. Etc.
You should do this:

```
def altogether():
    threading.Timer(3.0, match_file).start() # Passing match_file into the timer
    return
```

OR:

```
threading.Timer(3.0, altogether).start() # Initialize outside the methode.
def altogether():
    match_file()
    return
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent :) unfortunately for the first option, i got as a result

Comment: Thanks Vincent :) unfortunately for the first option, i got as a result        ['good1', 'good2'] without it running the script every 3 seconds. 

i tried changing it to 
    def altogether():
            while True:
                match_file()
                time.sleep(3)

and that gave me the same result so it has got to do with the for loop on the top.  ill try to work on that more.  thanks though!